# Removing a View from an Activity

Tags: android

You've got a View defined in a layout file. How do you remove it from you Activity code?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(myView.getParent());
vg.removeView(myView);
```

should do what you want as far as correctly removing the View from the Activity. The other guys' answer will just make the View invisible, using up resources.

Comment: Does this works for `ContentView` added by `addContentView(View v, LayoutParams params)`

Comment: The problem here is that how do you get the myView in the first place when you are inside the Activity Class.

Comment: vg.setVisibility(View.GONE); can also use

Answer (score 2):

As [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674530/android) mentioned in a comment:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Quoting the Android reference:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

I think it's the best solution unless you **really** need to delete the object.